# retrieving data from field which has multiple values

Tags: google-bigquery

```
We have table person. It has sample fields with multiple values like

person

ID name  tripNumber startPlace   endPlace
1  xxx    20         Portland    Atlanta
          25         California  Atlanta
          40         America     Africa
2  EKVV   40         America     Africa
          37         Argentina   Carolina

We need to retrieve entire row of data in particular condition like tripNumber=40 and endPlace="Africa"

We need the result like this,

ID name  tripNumber startPlace   endPlace
1  xxx    40         America     Africa
2  EKVV   40         America     Africa
```

Comment: how you expect to match values from different columns? by position?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.person` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'xxx' name, [20, 25, 40] tripNumber, ['Portland', 'California', 'America'] startPlace, ['Atlanta', 'Atlanta', 'Africa'] endPlace UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  'EKVV', [40, 37], ['America', 'Argentina'], ['Africa', 'Carolina']
)
SELECT id, name, tripNumber, startPlace[SAFE_OFFSET(off)] startPlace, endPlace[SAFE_OFFSET(off)] endPlace 
FROM `project.dataset.person`,
UNNEST(tripNumber) tripNumber WITH OFFSET off
WHERE tripNumber = 40
```

with result

```
Row id  name    tripNumber  startPlace  endPlace     
1   1   xxx     40          America     Africa   
2   2   EKVV    40          America     Africa
```

Above solution assumes that you have independent repeated fields and match to be done based on positions in respective arrays

Below - is based on more common pattern of having repeated record

so if `person` table would look like below

```
Row id  name    trips.tripNumber    trips.startPlace    trips.endPlace   
1   1   xxx     20                  Portland            Atlanta  
                25                  California          Atlanta  
                40                  America             Africa   
2   2   EKVV    40                  America             Africa   
                37                  Argentina           Carolina
```

in this case solution would be

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.person` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'xxx' name, [STRUCT<tripNumber INT64, startPlace STRING, endPlace STRING>(20, 'Portland', 'Atlanta'),(25, 'California', 'Atlanta'),(40, 'America', 'Africa')] trips UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'EKVV', [STRUCT(40, 'America', 'Africa'),(37, 'Argentina', 'Carolina')]
)
SELECT id, name, tripNumber, startPlace, endPlace 
FROM `project.dataset.person`,
UNNEST(trips) trip
WHERE tripNumber = 40
```

with result

```
Row id  name    tripNumber  startPlace  endPlace     
1   1   xxx     40          America     Africa   
2   2   EKVV    40          America     Africa
```